# Output iterator on a set: assign and increment iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, set, stdvector

There are many questions about output iterator and sets but none of them address this particular topic.

I writing a function to deserialize a sequence of objects to a container.  I wish this function be as general as possible, so container can be either a set or a vector.

I'm thinking on receiving an OutputIterator as argument where to put each new object as they are deserialized.  I'm not sure what to expect when writing to the iterator if the container is a set.

To be brief, let say the containers in this example hold int instead of pointers to objects, returned one by one by `getIntFromInput()`.

```
void deserializeToContainer(OutputIterator oit){
  while(moreInputAvailable()){
    *oit = getIntFromInput();
    oit++;
  }
}

void deserializeToVector(vector<int> &vectorContainer){
  deserializeToContainer(vectorContainer.back_inserter());
}

void deserializeToSet(set<int> &setContainer){
  deserializeToContainer(setContainer.end());
}
```

Since set hasn't a back_inserter, and elements aren't stored in the order they are inserted, I wonder what to expect about `*oit` assignment and `oit` increment when the container is a set, like in `deserializeToSet`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`std::insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator) (probably with [`std::inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter))

```
void deserializeToSet(set<int> &setContainer){
  deserializeToContainer(std::inserter(setContainer, setContainer.end()));
}
```